# Why Hashmap.values().parallelStream() does not run in parallel while wrap them in ArrayList could work?

Tags: java, java-stream, spliterator

The hashmap has two key and value pairs, they are not processed in parallel by different threads.

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("a", 1);
        map.put("b", 2);
        map.values().parallelStream()
              .peek(x -> System.out.println("processing "+x+" in "+Thread.currentThread()))
              .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
processing 1 in Thread[main,5,main]
1
processing 2 in Thread[main,5,main]
2
```

URL: https://ideone.com/Hkxkoz

The ValueSpliterator should have tried to split the arrays of HashMap into slot of size 1, which means two elements should be processed in different threads.

Source: https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/java8.util.HMSpliterators$ValueSpliterator/%3Cinit%3E

After wrapped them in `ArrayList`, it works as expected.

```
        new ArrayList(map.values()).parallelStream()
              .peek(x -> System.out.println("processing "+x+" in "+Thread.currentThread()))
              .forEach(System.out::println);
```

output:

```
processing 1 in Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3,5,main]
1
processing 2 in Thread[main,5,main]
2
```

Comment: Note that the documentation for `parallelStream()` says "
Returns a possibly parallel Stream with this collection as its source. It is allowable for this method to return a sequential stream.". There is no guarantee that multiple threads will be used.

Comment: ...and considering that the stream is a sized stream, and very tiny, it would be a very sane choice not to return a parallel stream.

Comment: Is there code analysis? The high level documentation docs not help here.

Comment: Try with large dataset

Comment: @Kamel why do you care about the details? You've presented toy code which works according to specs ("possibly parallel stream") and you've been given a likely explanation why your stream isn't parallel (because it's tiny). You can dig into the source code if you want to of course, but I don't think you'll get any more significant information out of it.

Comment: Also see [spliterator characteristics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46644595/understanding-deeply-spliterator-characteristics) as well as a Java 8 (fixed in u60) [parallel bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259636/is-this-a-bug-in-files-lines-or-am-i-misunderstanding-something-about-paralle). The first one may give insight on why the wrapped list is processed in parallel. Maybe someone will write a proper write-up.

Comment: @Kayaman someone did…

Comment: @Holger well I can't say I'm surprised it was you :) thanks.

Comment: @Kayaman it is not toy program, if the method in `forEach` is time consuming, it is definitely necessary to run it in parallel.

Comment: @Kamel sorry, I thought you were talking about a different thing. But the explanation for that is in the answer linked in Holger's answer.

Comment: FYI: IdeOne tries to run your code as few times as possible, so generally it shows you a stored result. If the code is run repeatedly, offline on a PC, it will show all kind of variation, both the list and list-less variants can end up showing the main thread only, the main thread and a worker thread, or sometimes even the worker thread only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44802784/2711488), the issue is connected with the fact that the `HashMap` has a capacity potentially larger than its size and the actual values are distributed over the backing array based on their hash codes.

The splitting logic is basically the same for all array based spliterators, whether you stream over an array, an `ArrayList`, or a `HashMap`. To get balanced splits on a best-effort basis, each split will half the (index) range, but in case of `HashMap`, the number of actual elements within the range differs from the range size.

In principle, every range based spliterator can split down to single elements, however, the client code, i.e. the Stream API implementation, might not split so far. The decision for even attempting to split is driven by the expected number of elements and number of CPU cores.

Taking the following program

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("a", 1);
    map.put("b", 2);

    for(int depth: new int[] { 1, 2, Integer.MAX_VALUE }) {
        System.out.println("With max depth: "+depth);
        Tree<Spliterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>> spTree
            = split(map.entrySet().spliterator(), depth);
        Tree<String> valueTree = spTree.map(sp -> "estimated: "+sp.estimateSize()+" "
            +StreamSupport.stream(sp, false).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        System.out.println(valueTree);
    }
}

private static <T> Tree<Spliterator<T>> split(Spliterator<T> sp, int depth) {
    Spliterator<T> prefix = depth-- > 0? sp.trySplit(): null;
    return prefix == null?
        new Tree<>(sp): new Tree<>(null, split(prefix, depth), split(sp, depth));
}

public static class Tree<T> {
    final T value;
    List<Tree<T>> children;

    public Tree(T value) {
        this.value = value;
        children = Collections.emptyList();
    }
    public Tree(T value, Tree<T>... ch) {
        this.value = value;
        children = Arrays.asList(ch);
    }
    public <U> Tree<U> map(Function<? super T, ? extends U> f) {
        Tree<U> t = new Tree<>(value == null? null: f.apply(value));
        if(!children.isEmpty()) {
            t.children = new ArrayList<>(children.size());
            for(Tree<T> ch: children) t.children.add(ch.map(f));
        }
        return t;
    }
    public @Override String toString() {
        if(children.isEmpty()) return value == null? "": value.toString();
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);
        toString(sb, 0, 0);
        return sb.toString();
    }
    public void toString(StringBuilder sb, int preS, int preEnd) {
        final int myHandle = sb.length() - 2;
        sb.append(value == null? "": value).append('\n');
        final int num = children.size() - 1;
        if (num >= 0) {
            if (num != 0) {
                for (int ix = 0; ix < num; ix++) {
                    int nPreS = sb.length();
                    sb.append(sb, preS, preEnd);
                    sb.append("\u2502 ");
                    int nPreE = sb.length();
                    children.get(ix).toString(sb, nPreS, nPreE);
                }
            }
            int nPreS = sb.length();
            sb.append(sb, preS, preEnd);
            final int lastItemHandle = sb.length();
            sb.append("  ");
            int nPreE = sb.length();
            children.get(num).toString(sb, nPreS, nPreE);
            sb.setCharAt(lastItemHandle, '\u2514');
        }
        if (myHandle > 0) {
            sb.setCharAt(myHandle, '\u251c');
            sb.setCharAt(myHandle + 1, '\u2500');
        }
    }
}
```

you will get:

```
With max depth: 1

├─estimated: 1 [a=1, b=2]
└─estimated: 1 []

With max depth: 2

├─
│ ├─estimated: 0 [a=1, b=2]
│ └─estimated: 0 []
└─
  ├─estimated: 0 []
  └─estimated: 0 []

With max depth: 2147483647

├─
│ ├─
│ │ ├─
│ │ │ ├─estimated: 0 []
│ │ │ └─estimated: 0 [a=1]
│ │ └─
│ │   ├─estimated: 0 [b=2]
│ │   └─estimated: 0 []
│ └─
│   ├─
│   │ ├─estimated: 0 []
│   │ └─estimated: 0 []
│   └─
│     ├─estimated: 0 []
│     └─estimated: 0 []
└─
  ├─
  │ ├─
  │ │ ├─estimated: 0 []
  │ │ └─estimated: 0 []
  │ └─
  │   ├─estimated: 0 []
  │   └─estimated: 0 []
  └─
    ├─
    │ ├─estimated: 0 []
    │ └─estimated: 0 []
    └─
      ├─estimated: 0 []
      └─estimated: 0 []
```

<sup>On [ideone](https://ideone.com/z3f1g0)</sup>

So, as said, the spliterator can split down to individual elements if we split deep enough, however, the estimated size of two elements does not suggest that it’s worth doing that. On each split, it will halve the estimate and while you might say that it’s wrong for the elements you’re interested in, it’s actually correct for most spliterators here, as when going down to the maximum level, most spliterators are representing an empty range and splitting them turns out to be a waste of resources.

As said in the other answer, the decision is about balancing the work of splitting (or preparation in general) and the expected work to parallelize, which the Stream implementation can’t know in advance. If you know in advance that the per-element workload will be very high, to justify more preparation work, you can use, e.g. `new ArrayList<>(map.[keySet|entrySet|values]()) .parallelStream()` to enforce balanced splits. Usually, the problem will be much smaller for larger maps anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for [Holger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59087726/1392943), I will add more details here.

The root cause comes from the sizeEstimate inaccuracy for `HashMap.values()`.
By default, HashMap has the capacity of 16, with 2 elements, which backed by an array. The estimate size of the Spliterator is 2.

Every time, each split will halve the array by half. In this case, the 16 length of array is split into two, 8 in each half, and each half has estimate size of 1. As the elements are placed according to hashcode, unfortunately, two elements lie in the same half.

Then the forkjoin framework thinks 1 is [below the sizeThreshold](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/ForEachOps.java#l288), it will stop splitting and begin to process the task.

At the same time, arrayList does not have this problem, as the estimatedSize is always accurate.