# Java Spliterator Continually Splits Parallel Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I found some surprising behavior with Java parallel streams.  I made my own `Spliterator`, and the resulting parallel stream gets divided up until each stream has only one element in it.  That seems way too small and I wonder what I'm doing wrong.  I'm hoping there's some characteristics I can set to correct this.

Here's my test code.  The `Float` here is just a dummy payload, my real stream class is somewhat more complicated.

```
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      TestingSpliterator splits = new TestingSpliterator( 10 );
      Stream<Float> test = StreamSupport.stream( splits, true );
      double total = test.mapToDouble( Float::doubleValue ).sum();
      System.out.println( "Total: " + total );
   }
```

This code will continually split this stream until each `Spliterator` has only one element.  That seems way too much to be efficient.

Output:

```
run:
Split on count: 10
Split on count: 5
Split on count: 3
Split on count: 5
Split on count: 2
Split on count: 2
Split on count: 3
Split on count: 2
Split on count: 2
Total: 5.164293184876442
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Here's the code of the `Spliterator`.  My main concern is what characteristics I should be using, but perhaps there's a problem somewhere else?

```
public class TestingSpliterator implements Spliterator<Float> {
   int count;
   int splits;

   public TestingSpliterator( int count ) {
      this.count = count;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean tryAdvance( Consumer<? super Float> cnsmr ) {
      if( count > 0 ) {
         cnsmr.accept( (float)Math.random() );
         count--;
         return true;
      } else
         return false;
   }

   @Override
   public Spliterator<Float> trySplit() {
      System.err.println( "Split on count: " + count );
      if( count > 1 ) {
         splits++;
         int half = count / 2;
         TestingSpliterator newSplit = new TestingSpliterator( count - half );
         count = half;
         return newSplit;
      } else
         return null;
   }

   @Override
   public long estimateSize() {
      return count;
   }

   @Override
   public int characteristics() {
      return IMMUTABLE | SIZED;
   }
}
```

So how can I get the stream to be split in to much larger chunks?  I was hoping in the neighborhood of 10,000 to 50,000 would be better.

I know I can return `null` from the `trySplit()` method, but that seems like a backwards way of doing it.  It seems like the system should have some notion of number of cores, current load, and how complex the code is that uses the stream, and adjust itself accordingly.  In other words, I want the stream chunk size to be externally configured, not internally fixed by the stream itself.

EDIT: re. Holger's answer below, when I increase the number of elements in the original stream, the stream splits are somewhat less, so `StreamSupport` does stop splitting eventually.

At an initial stream size of 100 elements, `StreamSupport` stops splitting when it reaches a stream size of 2 (the last line I see on my screen is `Split on count: 4`).

And for an initial stream size of 1000 elements, the final size of the individual stream chunks is about 32 elements.

---

Edit part deux: After looking at the output of the above, I changed my code to list out the individual `Spliterator`s created.  Here's the changes:

```
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      TestingSpliterator splits = new TestingSpliterator( 100 );
      Stream<Float> test = StreamSupport.stream( splits, true );
      double total = test.mapToDouble( Float::doubleValue ).sum();
      System.out.println( "Total Spliterators: " + testers.size() );
      for( TestingSpliterator t : testers ) {
         System.out.println( "Splits: " + t.splits );
      }
   }
```

And to the `TestingSpliterator`'s ctor:

```
   static Queue<TestingSpliterator> testers = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

   public TestingSpliterator( int count ) {
      this.count = count;
      testers.add( this ); // OUCH! 'this' escape
   }
```

The result of this code is that the first `Spliterator` gets split 5 times. The next`Spliterator` gets split 4 times.  The next set of `Spliterators` get split 3 times.  Etc.  The result is that 36 `Spliterators` get made and the stream is split into as many parts.  On typical desktop systems this seems to be the way that the API thinks is the best for parallel operations.

I'm going to accept Holger's answer below, which is essentially that the `StreamSupport` class is doing the right thing, don't worry, be happy.  Part of the issue for me was that I was doing my early testing on very small stream sizes and I was surprised at the number of splits.  Don't make the same mistake yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking on it from the wrong angle. The implementation did not split “until each spliterator has one element”, it rather split “until having ten spliterators”.

A single spliterator instance can only be processed by one thread. A spliterator is not required to support splitting after its traversal has been started. Therefore any splitting opportunity that has not been used beforehand may lead to limited parallel processing capabilities afterwards.

It’s important to keep in mind that the Stream implementation received a `ToDoubleFunction` with an unknown workload¹. It doesn’t know that it is as simple as `Float::doubleValue` in your case. It could be a function taking a minute to evaluate and then, having a spliterator per CPU core would be righteous right. Even having more than CPU cores is a valid strategy to handle the possibility that some evaluations take significantly longer than others.

A typical number of initial spliterators will be “number of CPU cores” × 4, though here might be more split operations later when more knowledge about actual workloads exist. When your input data has less than that number, it’s not surprising when it gets split down until one element per spliterator is left.

You may try with `new TestingSpliterator( 10000 )` or `1000` or `100` to see that the number of splits will not change significantly, once the implementation assumes to have enough chunks to keep all CPU cores busy.

Since your spliterator does not know anything about the per-element workload of the consuming stream either, you shouldn’t be concerned about this. If you can smoothly support splitting down to single elements, just do that.

¹ It doesn’t have special optimizations for the case that no operations have been chained, though.

Comment: At 100 elements `StreamSupport` will split down to an stream length of 2 (the last split I see printed is `Split on count: 4`) and for a total length of 1000 elements the splits go down to about 32 elements.  I'll update my question.

Comment: I'm still somewhat surprised that it works this way though, it seems pernicious in many cases to split this much.  I'm still trying to wrap my head around the idea that this could be desired as a default behavior.

Comment: As said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44802784/) “*If you request parallel, you get parallel, even if it actually reduces the performance.*” As shown there, you may even process two elements in parallel when the workload is large enough. Note that splitting that deep does not imply that it runs on different threads; if the actual workload is low, the locally processing thread may take the next chunk before another thread picked it up. Then, you only have the minor overhead of having created another lightweight object. There’s no magic threshold for “parallel will have a benefit”

Comment: OK I'm convinced that the `StreamSupport` class isn't broken and its behavior is reasonable.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am missing the obvious, you could always pass a `bufferSize` in the constructor and use that for your `trySplit`:

```
@Override
public Spliterator<Float> trySplit() {

     if( count > 1 ) {
        splits++;
        if(count > bufferSize) {
            count = count - bufferSize;
            return new TestingSpliterator( bufferSize, bufferSize);
        }

    }
    return null;
}
```

And with this:

```
TestingSpliterator splits = new TestingSpliterator(12, 5);
Stream<Float> test = StreamSupport.stream(splits, true);

test.map(x -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
                   x.doubleValue(), 
                   Thread.currentThread().getName()))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Map.Entry::getValue, 
                Collectors.mapping(
                     Map.Entry::getKey, 
                     Collectors.toList())))
    .forEach((x, y) -> System.out.println("Thread : " + x + " processed : " + y));
```

You would see that there are 3 threads. Two of them process `5` elements and one `2`.

Comment: Well, I guess the obvious here is that I was hoping there was something that the API provided that would do this for me.  I'm a bit surprised that I have to manage this myself, that the API doesn't provide a sensible default splitting.  I'm going to poke at this a bit more, but thanks very much for the input.

Comment: Of course, it would be backwards if a spliterator decided what `bufferSize` was efficient, without knowing the actual stream operation. Someone decided to turn the stream of ten elements to parallel (pass `true` to `StreamSupport.stream( splits, true )`) and it’s not the task of the Stream API implementation (nor spliterator) to effectively turn off parallel processing when the one who knows what work is supposed to be done decided to do parallel.